# Parallax issue on mobile vs. desktop with narrower browser

Tags: css, mobile, parallax

I am working on creating a parallax-ish scrolling effect for the mobile version of my site. The effect works fine on a desktop when I shrink the browser, or when I use Chrome's mobile viewer, but it doesn't work on my phone.

Here's the live example. Shrink your browser below 980px wide to see the effect. http://imbibe.staging.wpengine.com/

It appears that on mobile, the background image is shown at full size, and doesn't remain fixed.

It's just a CSS effect, no js or anything. Let me know what more details I can provide and I will! Thanks.

Comment: I was under the impression that parallax scroll was usually disabled on mobile devices. It's processor intensive and slow. You may have to use JavaScript to get the desired effect.

Comment: @Knostradamus thanks for the info! Do you happen to have any links or resources about that? I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here's something that I remember stumbling across a while back. It's old but it goes into some detail. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/parallax-scrolling-that-actually-works-on-ipad/